# Create Html Tables using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to create HTML tables using jquery?  I have tried using simple javascript but it has not given me fruitful results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like,

```
var $table=$('<table border="1"/>');
$table.append('<tr><td>Column 1</td><tr>');
$table.appendTo('body');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QDNQF/1/)